# Log in as administrator in acumos

Tags: acumos

I'm following [this guide](https://docs.acumos.org/en/latest/AcumosUser/oneclick-deploy/user-guide.html) to deploy acumos.

After `sudo bash one_click_deploy.sh` I need to complete Hippo CMS setup :

> In your browser goto the Hippo CMS component at http://acumos:9080 and
>   login as “admin/admin”

This port give me nothing, in my case it's 30443 (as indicated in the logs from one_click_deploy script)

I can create user and login, but I cannot login as admin and manage (and also cannot access http://acumos:30443/cms/console to continue process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AIO guide needs an update (I'll do that) to clarify that the CMS is accessible at the port defined in acumos-env.sh, by default port 30980. The CMS console path (where you update the CMS hosts structures) is http://acumos:30980/cms/console.

The port for the portal-marketplace is by default 30443, i.e. to login to the Acumos portal, browse to https://acumos:30443 and accept the untrusted server certificate. Note that the CMS is accessed on a different port vs the portal, as described above.

Comment: Thank you ! This was really helpful.
I saw that you 've updated the guide also, I followed it and the create-user.sh doesn't seem to work at first sight. I got an error (fail to create user) but it seems that the user is created, I can log in. I don't know if it just me.
Anyway, thanks for the answer and the new guide.

Comment: I made again the install process, no issue with create-user, I probably miss something first time.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the latest from https://gerrit.acumos.org/r/system-integration and in the AIO directory ran the setup in an Ubuntu 16.04 VM.  After all the docker containers were up I checked docker ps output and found the acumos-cms-docker listening on port 30980.  This is per the setting in the acumos-env.sh file; I don't know how the container might have been mapped to port 30443.  Anyhow I was able to get a screen at this URL:  http://acumos:30980/cms